# TFS Build Failures - What does CollectFromChildProcesses in .RunSettings do?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tfs, msbuild

Forgive me if this seems a little outside of SO standards, but we've been having issues with builds failing tests in TFS - specifically, integration tests that call out to a database. That database is provided to the TFS build agent via a SQLLocalDb instance.

This works most of the time, but we started geting random failures with SQL appearing to go offline half way through the test run.

After much rewriting and refusing to admit the SQL server can just dissapear, we stumbled across the setting...

```
<CollectFromChildProcesses>true</CollectFromChildProcesses>
```

...in the build .runsettings file, based upon https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb/issues/7.

**Changing it to false appears to have alleviated our issues.**

However, I can find anything to explain what that setting controls and if we're lining up other issues by persuing this as a fix?

Appreciate anyone with a knowledge share.

Comment: What's the detail errors? Based on the name, it is used for collection data from the child process, so it won't block current process.

Comment: The errors vary but they all essentially mean that sql server is unavailable. On its own that would be easy to triage but it happens intermittently on different tests at different times.

Comment: You said that "Changing it to false appears to have alleviated our issues.", so do you mean the issue still persist even though set CollectionFromChildprocesses to true? What's the result if you try it with another SQL Server?

Comment: It is an intermittent issue that goes away when set to 'false'. Switching it to 'true' and it eventually starts to reoccur again. We use (localdb) SQL as this keeps it sandboxed and consistent across developer workstations and  build agents. I'd be happy to accept another solution. but really I just want to know if this setting will cause anything else to change under the hood.